# Converting coordinates into GeoJSON string with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, geojson, coordinates, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to write some code that gets the coordinates of a point, line or polygon, then I have to convert these coordinates into a GeoJSON string. I'm currently just trying to print it to make sure its converting but eventually it will need to be updated in a PostGIS table. What I have throws up no errors but doesn't print the string:

```py
# update geometry column 
def update_geojson():
    from qgis.core import QgsGeometry
    from qgis.core import QgsJsonExporter
import json
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    coordinates = json.loads(geom.asJson())['coordinates'][0]
def qGeometry(feature):
    try:
        geom = QgsGeometry(feature.geometry())
        fid = feature.id()
        if not geom.isMultipart():
            if not geom.convertToMultiType():
                raise Exception("unable to extract feature geometry (invalid geometry type)")
        if geom.type() == 0:
            return qPoints(geom.asMultiPoint())
        elif geom.type() == 1:
            return qLines(geom.asMultiPolyline(), fid)
        elif geom.type() == 2:
            return qPolygons(geom.asMultiPolygon(), fid)
        else:
            raise Exception("unable to extract feature geometry (unknown geometry type)")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("unable to extract feature geometry: %s" % unicode(e))
        
        def json_string_update():
            json_string = json.dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features})
            for i in (json_string):
                print(i)
        json_string_update()
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Is it really formatted like that? The only bits that will get run are the 4 lines after `import json`. No other code is used, none of your functions are called, you import packages inside a function (that doesn't get called) so no code outside the functions can access those packages, you define a function inside an exception block that can never be called as it's defined directly after you `raise Exception` which is inside another function that doesn't get called.

Comment: yes, im new to python and qgis so this has been a struggle but thanks for your pointers, they have helped

Comment: The main two issues are 1. that indentation is important in Python, it's part of the syntax and is not just decoration and 2. code in functions doesn't get run unless you call the function.